# prepared statements and databases

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Data does not enter the database. I can create the table, but can not insert data from the form. All I see are zeros.

My last question, it was suggested that I use prepared statements. So, I mimicked the manual. I've simplified the code all I can. Other questions suggested to define the variables before binding the statements, and I've tried moving the variables around. (Note: that the $user variable is from a required file)

```
/* Non-prepared statement */
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profiles") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE profiles
    (user VARCHAR(16), text VARCHAR(355))")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$text = sanitizeString($_POST['text']);
$text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);


/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles
    (user, text) VALUES (?,?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */

if (!$stmt->bind_param("ii", $user, $text)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

/* explicit close recommended */
$stmt->close();
```

I expect for the database columns to created. However, user data entered into the form from the browser does not record. Instead, I am seeing one line of zeros every time I try.

Comment: try to minimize the php argument.

Answer (score 0):

You pass integers into your table on line

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ii", $user, $text)) {
                        ^^
```

`i` is integer, `s` is string.

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $text)) {
```